# Why doesn't the Gmail "mute" button show up for me?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations, mute

In Gmail, there's a nice feature where you can "mute" a thread so that new replies on it no longer get marked as new, so that you aren't bothered by them any more. (Supposedly. I've never actually seen it in my own account. I understand that it's supposed to be in the "More Actions" menu.) This is (would be) particularly useful when a member of a mailing list and there is a popular thread that you're *just not interested in*.

I don't seem to have it for either my standard Gmail account, or my Google Mail for domains account.

The only reason I can fathom is that I am already using filters to apply labels to mail from mailing lists so that I can easily flip through unread messages on a single topic. Here's an example rule that I'm using:

```
Matches: to:(model-glue@googlegroups.com)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "CF-ModelGlue", Never send it to Spam
```

Is it known that filtering messages like this will remove the mute functionality? Is there some other way to get my labels and retain the mute functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the mute button come back when filtering by including the `is:unread` filter and adding `-is:muted`. I have the following query displayed beneath my inbox using the Multiple Inboxes lab, and it allows me to mute conversations:

```
label:Support is:unread -is:muted
```

This shows me anything labelled Support that I haven't read, and that isn't muted yet. The mute button can be found under the More Actions button as usual.

Comment: you don't have to add is:unread; just -is:muted works fine

Comment: where to add  -is:muted in create filter dialog box of gmail?

Answer (score 8):

The Mute option is only enabled if your message is also in the inbox. Since your filter has the "Skip inbox" you will never see it

Comment: if the message is not in the inbox, you can add -is:muted in the filter input box to make the mute button reappear

Answer (score 6):

The menu item for Mute normally only appears in the inbox. It doesn't appear in label views that contain a mix of inbox and non-inbox items. In a message, you can only mute a message that's in the inbox (and not just any view of the message - if you search for a message and find one that's in the inbox, you can't mute it unless you viewed it from the inbox). The keyboard shortcut key for 'mute' is 'm'.   You can find muted messages by searching for `is:mute`.

If you have a particular search, such as a filter or label, you can add `-is:mute` to the search criteria and it enables the Mute menu item on those search results.

Comment: A clever idea, but it doesn't seem to do anything for me. :(

Comment: @Adam: do you have hotkeys enabled?

Comment: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47787

Comment: Yes, I specifically enabled them to test this.

Comment: I see this issue intermittently. I can still mute using `m` when the menu option is missing.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the system.

You will need to collect your messages without the `label:yourlabel` search.

i.e. When you are creating/editing the filter, do a Test Search based on your filter. This will bring up all the results.

From here you will find the once missing Mute Option in the More Actions Menu for each message.

A second way would be have a second tab viewing Gmail in basic HTML, instead of Standard View. In Basic HTML the Mute Option is visible again.

Comment: I wish I could find out who down-voted this, because they couldn't be more wrong. This is exactly correct. It's unfortunate, but at least now I know how to find the Mute button when I really need it. Thanks!

Comment: I think the same thing comes up when you navigate to the message from the "All Mail" view. Go to the inbox, then navigate to the message from the inbox, and the mute button should show up.

Answer (score 0):

It shows up in mine when I click on an email, then click on more actions it is at the bottom of the list.

```
More Actions -> Mute
```

Answer (score 0):

for me you have to right-click the email in order to find the "mute" option it doesn't appear under the regular three-dot More options